# Adjusting radius of Shield UI donut chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am using a Shield UI Donut chart and I am in need to achieve some special layout of my chart. What I need is to have some of my points, let’s say the half of them displayed in one donut chart, and the other half again in a donut chart that to be surrounding the first one. Or to have two donut charts in one another. 
And if this is possible how can I have adjust the radius of my donut charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be in need is not possible. First of all because you may only have one chart per container. Speaking in terms of what the Shield UI Charting library permits. What you may find more useful is to try the polar charts series, where data is displayed around a center point.

In addition there isn’t a radius property for the donut chart. You may adjust dimensions by the width and height of the chart to achieve any special effects if needed.